# Inflate layout on page change in viewpager

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

In my app, I have a view pager with two tabs and I have two layouts and I want to inflate and show layout1.xml inside the tab when the user switches to tab #1 and inflate and show layout2.xml inside the tab when user switches to tab #2, but I cannot find how to do it.

Any help will be very much appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create two fragments
2. Inflate one of the layouts in each fragments `onCreateView()` and return the view.
3. Return an instance of fragment 1 for the position 0 in your `FragmentPagerAdapter`s `getItem()` method and an instance of fragment 2 for position 1.